# Is there a way to make DataSet aware of database changes automatically?

Tags: .net, dataset

I fetched around 10,000 records from the database and filled the DataSet. If someone changes the Database, I want the DataSet to get updated automatically.

Is there any built-in feature in .NET to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can take a look at [`SqlCacheDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx) , it establishes a relationship between an item stored in an ASP.NET application's Cache object and either a specific SQL Server database table or the results of a SQL Server 2005 query

Comment: What if it is a Windows based application?

Comment: @RPK - look at [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx).